# Display Dates from a List in a CalendarView Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I have a CalendarioView from this `Xamarin.Plugin.Calendar` nuget package.
I've been following [this tutorial](https://bertuzzi.medium.com/o-x-do-xamarin-forms-calendar-view-b76a7fcf24e1), and I want to have the same result. Instead of assigning the `EventCollection` list manually, as in the example, I have my List.
How to fill it in the EventCollection? I've searched and didn't find anything that worked.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:c ="clr-namespace:Minha_Carteira_Hospitalar.Controls"
         x:Class="Minha_Carteira_Hospitalar.Views.PlanoReceita"
         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Plugin.Calendar.Controls;assembly=Xamarin.Plugin.Calendar">

<controls:Calendar
    Events="{Binding Events}"
    >
    <controls:Calendar.EventTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout Padding="15,0,0,0">
                <Label
                Text="{Binding Name}"
                FontAttributes="Bold"
                FontSize="Medium" />
               
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:Calendar.EventTemplate>
</controls:Calendar>
```

MVVM code

```
 public EventCollection Events;
    public ObservableCollection<Plans> myPlans= new ObservableCollection<Plans>();
    public ObservableCollection<Plans> MyPlans
    {
        get => myPlans;
        set => myPlans= value;
    }
    public MyPlansViewModel()
    {
        Events = new EventCollection();
    }
    public ICommand LoadingMyPlans
    {
        get
        {

            return new Command(async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    List<Plans> tmp = await App.Database.GetMyPlans();
                    foreach(var item in tmp)
                    {
                        MyPlans.Clear();
                        tmp.ForEach(i => MyPlans.Add(i));

                        Events.Add(item.DatePlan, MyPlans);
                    }
                    
                  
                   
                    
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "OK");
                }

            });

        }
    }
```

Comment: you can only bind to public properties - `Events` is not a property

Comment: I think that is the same cenario in `ListView`. But, in this case, what i can do?

Comment: make `Events` a property.  This is a basic C# concept.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties

Comment: I switched `Events` to property and the data is still not showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure where you use the `LoadingMyPlans` for. I make a simple example about how to fill your own list into `EventCollection` for your reference.

The same Xaml as yours.

Model:

```
  public class Plans
{
    public DateTime dateTime { get; set; }
    public List<Plan> plans { get; set; }
}
public class Plan
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
    public class CalendarViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(storage, value))
        {
            return false;
        }

        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
    public EventCollection Events { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Plans> plans { get; set; }

    public CalendarViewModel()
    {
        plans = new ObservableCollection<Plans>()
        {
            new Plans(){ dateTime=DateTime.Now, plans=new List<Plan>() { new Plan() { Name = "Plan_A", Desc = "aaaaa" }, new Plan() { Name = "Plan_A2", Desc = "aaaaa2" } }},
            new Plans(){ dateTime=DateTime.Now.AddDays(5), plans=new List<Plan>() { new Plan() { Name = "Plan_B", Desc = "bbbbb" }, new Plan() { Name = "Plan_B2", Desc = "aaaaa2" } }},
            new Plans(){ dateTime=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3), plans=new List<Plan>() { new Plan() { Name = "Plan_C", Desc = "ccccc" }}}
        };
        Events = new EventCollection();
        foreach (var item in plans)
        {
            Events.Add(item.dateTime, item.plans);
        }

    }

}
```

Code behind:

```
   public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = new CalendarViewModel();
    }
```

[image]